51 points are inside a square of side length 1. Prove that we can cover some three of them by a circle with radius $\frac{1}{7}$
The traditional answer uses the pigeonhole principle to solve this, but I attempted a different way and I can't figure out why my solution is incorrect. I attempt to show this by finding the expected value of points covered by the circle. If the expected value is greater than 2, then there must be some circle that covers atleast 3 points (yeah its kind of the pigeonhole principle still).
My approach goes as such: suppose we look at an arbitrary point $P$ (out of the 51 points). Then the region where the circle will cover the point $P$ is a circular region with $P$ as its center and radius $\frac{1}{7}$; let's call this region the success region. So the area of the success region is $\pi(\frac{1}{7})^2 = \frac{\pi}{49}$. Now, we find the total area where the circle could lie. This region can be found by simply adding $\frac{1}{7}$ to all sides of the square, resulting in a $\frac{9}{7} \times \frac{9}{7}$ square. This total region has area $\frac{81}{49}$. So the probability that a circle randomly placed contains point $P$ is $$\frac{\frac{\pi}{49}}{\frac{81}{49}} = \frac{\pi}{81}.$$
Now since $P$ was arbitrarily chosen, by linearity of expectation, we can add up all the probabilities for the 51 points to get the expected number of points covered $$51\cdot \frac{\pi}{81} \approx 1.978.$$
But this is not greater than 2, so I failed to prove my point. Why is that? What is wrong with my approach?

If the expected value is greater than 2, then the question is solved; but for the question to be solved, it is not necessary that the expected value is greater than 2. So it's possible that your idea was reasonable, and everything you did is correct, but the method just doesn't work because of this.

Expected values are the wrong frame, I think: they don't need to have anything to do with the worst-case result. In a nonuniform distribution in which the elements of the 51-point set $S$ tend to cluster, you could make the expected number of other points of $S$ in a circle centered on an element of $S$ as high as you want (up to 50, if course). Your implicit assumption of a uniform distribution means that expected values track areas, so an expected value > 2 would just mean that you couldn't fill the square $[-1/7, 8/7]^2$ with 51 circles without covering some point thrice.

One can cover a square of side $7$ with $25$ regular hexagons of diameter $2$ like in the picture below

Notice that the top side of the square is just above the line of the sides of hexagons, so some extra hexagons ($3$ ) are needed for the cover, since $4 \sqrt{3} = 6.928\ldots < 7$.
Now, from $51$ points, $3$ will lie in the same hexagon ( box principle).
$\bf{Added:}$ The above may be the traditional answer. Let's see what some "pronbabilistic" answer might be.  Consider disks of radius $\frac{1}{7}$ centered at the points. We would like to show that $3$ of them will have a common point. That certainly happens if the total area of the disks is $> 2 \times$ area involved.  We say area involved and not the area of the square, since the disks might get outside the square.  Now, total area of disks is $51 \pi (\frac{1}{7})^2$, while the area involved is the region with distance $\le \frac{1}{7}$ from the square, that is
$$(1+\frac{2}{7})^2 - (\frac{2}{7})^2 + \pi (\frac{1}{7})^2$$
As luck would have it, it turns out that the first number is just under twice the second one ( wow....) so this argument would not work just out of the box
( so we had a comparison of covering vs packing )
The argument would have worked for any $51$ regions of that area  if  we had the desired inequality

Your method has merit and may work, not sure. Below is a possible alternate solution you could go for, by finding a way to separate the square into groups and using pigeonhole principle:

 Consider placing a circle of radius $\frac{1}{7}$ at $\left (\frac{2m + 1}{7\sqrt{2}}, \frac{2n + 1}{7\sqrt{2}}\right )$ for all $0 \leq m, n \leq 4$. Then this bounds a square of size $\frac{10}{7\sqrt{2}} > 1$. Hence, the unit square of the problem can be completely covered by the $25$ circles in this collection. But then by pigeonhole principle there exist 3 points contained by the same circle, so we’re done.

